# How to change values of multiple of Group Policy Objects on Windows Server?

Tags: windows, group-policy

How to change values of multiple of Group Policy Objects on Windows Server, is there any commercial tool out there? or PowerShell is the way to go forward?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Maybe with some scripting? Btw, software recommendations are off-topic here. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com may be your friend.

Comment: Please let us know what value you want to change, powershell can help, but it depend of the value you change